# How to tidyr data from a dataframe (wikipedia internal links)?

Tags: r, wikipedia

I am working on wikipedia internal links using WikipediR package
I am looking for internal links about Hérodote, (in french)

```
 install.packages("WikipediR")
 library (WikipediR)

 all_bls <- page_backlinks("fr","wikipedia",
                            page =  "Hérodote",
                            clean_response = TRUE)

all_bls_df  <- as.data.frame(all_bls) # converting in d.f
```

my result:

[image]

```
str(all_bls_df)
## 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  50 variables:
##  $ structure.c..60....0....Attributs.du.pharaon.....Names...c..pageid...           : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","60","Attributs du pharaon": 2 1 3
##  $ structure.c..133....0....Apis.....Names...c..pageid....ns....title.             : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","133","Apis": 2 1 3
##  $ structure.c..152....0....Anthropologie.....Names...c..pageid...                 : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","152","Anthropologie": 2 1 3
##  $ structure.c..159....0....Asie.....Names...c..pageid....ns....title.             : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","159","Asie": 2 1 3
##  $ structure.c..325....0....Ahmôsis.II.....Names...c..pageid...                    : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","325","Ahmôsis II": 2 1 3
##  $ structure.c..412....0....Bastet.....Names...c..pageid....ns...                  : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","412","Bastet": 2 1 3
##  $ structure.c..542....0....Corse.....Names...c..pageid....ns...                   : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","542","Corse": 2 1 3
##  $ structure.c..715....0....Cyclades.....Names...c..pageid....ns...                : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","715","Cyclades": 2 1 3
## (goes on for 42 more variables)
```

How can I tidy my `data.frame` object?

Expect result:

```
pageid     title
60         Attributs du pharaon
133        Apis
152        Antropologie
159        Asie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're using returns named character vectors in a list. We can use `purrr::map_df()` with `as.list()`. `map_df()` will execute the `as.list()` on each element in your `all_bls` list and automagically row-bind them into a data frame:

```
purrr::map_df(all_bls, as.list) 
## # A tibble: 50 × 3
##    pageid    ns                title
##     <chr> <chr>                <chr>
## 1      60     0 Attributs du pharaon
## 2     133     0                 Apis
## 3     152     0        Anthropologie
## 4     159     0                 Asie
## 5     325     0           Ahmôsis II
## 6     412     0               Bastet
## 7     542     0                Corse
## 8     715     0             Cyclades
## 9     734     0     Culte à mystères
## 10    821     0           Chamanisme
## # ... with 40 more rows
```